# Is this the correct way that this code works?

Tags: python-2.7

```
data = "000000000000000117c80378b8da0e33559b5997f2ad55e2f7d18ec1975b9717"
result1 = data.decode('hex')[::-1]
```

1. The hex data are decoded to decimal, which is `6,860,217,587,554,922,525,607,992,740,653,361,396,256,930,700,588,249,487,127`
2. Then the decimal number `6,860,217,587,554,922,525,607,992,740,653,361,396,256,930,700,588,249,487,127` is converted to bits and reversed its order (little-endian) and stored in `result1` variable as a bitarray?

Is this what exactly happens with that code or did I misunderstood anything? 
So the `result1` variable is a bitarray?

If it's just a integer variable, how can it hold that much long decimal value?

Answer (score 0):

[Strings in python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm) are declared using double or single quotes, therefore the variable **data** contains a string.
You can check the type of a variable directly in python:

```
data = "000000000000000117c80378b8da0e33559b5997f2ad55e2f7d18ec1975b9717"
type(data)
```

which outputs

```
str
```

meaning that the variable is a string.
When you call the function decode('hex') on a string you obtain another string:

```
data.decode('hex')
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x17\xc8\x03x\xb8\xda\x0e3U\x9bY\x97\xf2\xadU\xe2\xf7\xd1\x8e\xc1\x97[\x97\x17'
```

Every character in your original string is interpreted as an hexadecimal number, and every pairs of hexadecimal numbers - e.s. "17" - is converted into an hexadecimal character using the escape sequence \x - becoming "\x17".

When you write "\x41" you are basically telling python to interpret 41 as a single ASCII character whose hexadecimal representation is 41.

The [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) contains the hexadecimal, decimal and octal values associated to the ascii characters.

If you try for example

```
"48454C4C4F".decode('hex')
```

you obtain the string "HELLO"

Lastly when you use [::-1] on a string you reverse it:

```
"48454C4C4F".decode('hex')[::-1]
```

produces the string "OLLEH"

You can find more about the escape characters reading the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).